When does pseudo random becomes true random?
Pseudo Random is computer generated, meaning that if we know the algorithm behind the generation, we would know the outcomes of the random function.
Only in the real world, there is true random.
Given a pseudo random number that uses N paramters to determine the output of a integer, $f(x)$.
To make the following easier, we create a function $m$ to generate the params for $f$ given a seed:
$$m(x)=\{q(N(x-1)+i)|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
We first use a already known algorithm $q$ to predict N integers and make it the input for the function, where $q$ can take in a seed to generate a pseudo-random integer:
$$x=m(1)$$
$$f(x)=\alpha_1$$
Then, we generate a set from $f(m(1))$ to $f(m(N))$ to get another N input for $f$ using the function $\gamma$
$$\gamma(x)=\{f(m(N(x-1)+i))|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
$$f(\gamma(1))=\gamma_1$$
As you can see, it is starting to turn into a recursive function.
$$\gamma^1(x) = \{f(\gamma(N(x-1)+i))|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
$$\gamma^2(x) = \{f(\gamma^1(N(x-1)+i))|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
$$\gamma^3(x) = \{f(\gamma^2(N(x-1)+i))|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
$$\gamma^4(x) = \{f(\gamma^3(N(x-1)+i))|i \in \mathbb{N}, i>0, i \leq N\}$$
$$...$$
There is a saying that if you know the state of every atom, subatomic particles, and quantum particles, you can predict the outcome of the real world. But that is the definition of a pseudo-random algorithm.
My question is, if this saying is real, then the real world is just a complex reaction chain of states. My recursion equation describes a chain reaction from using a single psuedo-random function. If we get the output of this function for $N=G$, where $G$ is Graham's number:
$$\gamma^{G}(1)$$

Will the output be more random (or posses more entropy) than the most random outcome in the real world?
What is the radius of the enclosed system for this to fit the Bekenstein bound?

P.S. If this is absurd to you, I am terribly sorry to cause you to read through my statements and questions. I stumbled on this question while learning set theory and computer science, and I am still in the infancy of undestandign set theory and mathematical reasoning.

Maybe "there is a saying", but quantum mechanics says that is wrong: it is, in principle, impossible to predict the result of a measurement of an observable when the system's state is not an eigenstate of that observable.  But that belongs to physics rather than mathematics.

This question is similar to: How to generate REAL random numbers with some random and pseudo random. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TankutBeygu Somehow my search engine did not render me this result... But it pretty much solves my question
